# Cómo usar el graficador de funciones de google?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

me gustaría saber el modo de implementar un graficador de funciones en mi página web, algo así como el que que tiene el buscador de google, esto es, cuando por ejemplo pones en el buscador una función como esta: f(x)=x^2+1, lo cual muestra un hermoso gráfico.

Si se pudiera implementar ese mismo graficador de google, sería estupendo, he buscado pero solo me salen referencias del spreadsheets que hace gráficos de barras, circulares, etc, pero lo que necesito es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De no ser posible implementar el graficador de google, podrían darme alguna otra sugerencia de cómo graficar funciones del tipo lineal, cuadrática o exponencial de alguna otra forma en html5? Genial si es con JavaScript.

gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oficialmente no existe un api para usar las funciones de graficación de funciones de google, pero podrías usar math.js para hacer algo parecido

http://mathjs.org/

que soporta unidades y tiene un buen parser de expresiones.

Para hacer el plot puedes usar la siguiente libreria:

https://github.com/maurizzzio/function-plot

A continuacion te dejo un ejemplo funcional.

```js
function draw() {
    try {
      functionPlot({
        target: '#plot',
        data: [{
          fn: document.getElementById('eq').value,
          sampler: 'builtIn',  // this will make function-plot use the evaluator of math.js
          graphType: 'polyline'
        }]
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      alert(err);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    draw();
  };

  draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.2.1/math.min.js"></script>
<!-- load http://maurizzzio.github.io/function-plot/ -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/function-plot@1.14.0"></script>

  <style>
    input[type=text] {
      width: 300px;
    }
    input {
      padding: 6px;
    }
    body, html, input {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 11pt;

    }
    form {
      margin: 20px 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form">
  <label for="eq">Enter an equation:</label>
  <input type="text" id="eq" value="4 * sin(x) + 5 * cos(x/2)" />
  <input type="submit" value="Draw" />
</form>

<div id="plot"></div>
```

En el siguiente link tienes mas ejemplos:

https://maurizzzio.github.io/function-plot/

Comment: Me ha sido de gran ayuda muchas gracias!